# 20.04 wallpaper turned grey after BIOS update

Tags: desktop-background

I updated the BIOS on my XPS 9150 after being prompted by Software. After rebooting, the wallpaper is grey rather than the beautiful purple it was previously. (It still has the picture of the cat.) Not really a problem, but I'm curious why this happened. I've rebooted again with no change.

I also ran `sudo apt upgrade` prior to the BIOS upgrade, so I guess it could be related to that rather than the BIOS. I don't recall what that upgrade included, but I think there were 28 packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 cat backgrounds. The first is the default--the purple. There is also a gray version. Just go to settings > wallpaper and change it. It could have changed because they are similar name and after update were changed

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it just changed your background.

Try --> Rightklick on desktop --> change background --> select the purple variant of the cat